# ¿Cómo convertir una expresión infija en postfija?

Tags: c

Estoy trabajando con este código de convertir una expresión infija a Postfija. ¿Me pueden decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Lo que quiero es introducir la expresión infija y que lo trasforme a postfija, pero cuando ingreso la expresión, me imprime varios elementos basura.

El programa debería funcionar asi:

> ingrese una expresión: 3+4

> expresión postfija: 34+

```
void InfijaPosfija(struct Stack *ptr_abc, char *Expresion)
{
 char ExprPostfija[50];
 int i=0;
 char Simbolo;

 for(i=0; i <= strlen(Expresion);++i)
 {
    Simbolo = Expresion[i];
    
    if (Simbolo == '(')
    {   
        push(ptr_abc, Simbolo);
    }
    else{
        if (Simbolo == ')')
        {
            while(ptr_abc->Items[ptr_abc->Top] != '(')
            {
                ExprPostfija[i] = pop(ptr_abc);
            }
            pop(ptr_abc);
        }
        else{
            
            if (Simbolo >= 'a' && Simbolo<='z' || Simbolo >= 0 && Simbolo <= 9)
            {
                ExprPostfija[i] = Simbolo;      
            }
            else
            {
                if (Simbolo == '^' || '*' || '/' || '+' || '-')
                {
                    while(ptr_abc->Top != -1 && Priority(Simbolo) <= Priority(ptr_abc->Items[ptr_abc->Top]))
                    {
                        ExprPostfija[i] = pop(ptr_abc);
                    }
                    push(ptr_abc, Simbolo);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
 }
 while(ptr_abc->Top != -1)
 {
    ExprPostfija[i] = pop(ptr_abc);
    i++;
 } 
 printf("\n");
 printf("Expresion Postfija: %s\n",ExprPosfija);
}
```

Comment: Al parecer `if (Simbolo == '^' || '*' || '/' || '+' || '-')` no se puede hacer, debe ser `simbolo == 'a' && simbolo == 'b && ...`. Al hacer || de la forma que lo estás haciendo, siempre devolverá 1 (o true) al if por lo que recuerdo ya que es lo mismo que hacer `if('a') ...`

Comment: El código está incompleto. Falta la definición de `Stack` y de las funciones `pop`,  `push`. Pueden ser triviales, pero sin tenerlas a la vista, responder sería pura especulación.

Answer (score 1):

Para evaluar expresiones algebraicas primero hay que convertirlas a expresiones postfijas (RPN).

Para una situación real, donde hay que producir el resultado numérico, se usan dos stacks: uno para los valores, otro para los operadores. En este caso, como sólo interesa convertir la expresión, la salida impresa será nuestro "stack de valores".

Se usa un stack para almacenar las operaciones pendientes debido a que los operadores son de distintas prioridad, y hay que retenerlos hasta encontrar un operador de mayor prioridad que se evalúe primero.

Para simplificar el código a lo esencial, las variables son simples letras ('a' hasta la 'z') y no hay espacios en blanco.

Definamos primero el stack y sus operaciones.

```
typedef struct {
    char item[10];
    int ptr;        // Apunta a la primera celda libre.
} Stack;

void push(Stack* s, char val) {
    s->item[s->ptr++] = val;
}

int pop(Stack* s) {
    return s->item[--s->ptr];
}

int peek(Stack* s) {
    return s->item[s->ptr - 1];
}
```

La tabla de prioridades:

```
int priority(char x) {
    switch (x) {
        case '+':
        case '-': return 0;
        case '/':
        case '*': return 1;
        case '^': return 2;
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

La función de evaluación del stack se reduce simplemente a imprimir el operador. En una situación real, deberíamos sacar los operandos de un stack de valores. En esta función debería realizar la operación:

```
void evaluate(Stack* stack_ope) {
    char p = pop(stack_ope);
    //  Aqui debería evaluarse el operador contra el contenido del stack.
    printf("%c", p);
}
```

Finalmente, la función que evalúa una expresión algebraica:

```
void evaluar_expresion(char expresion[]) {
    Stack stack_ope;
    stack_ope.ptr = 0;
    
    printf("Evaluar %s = ", expresion);
    for (int i = 0; expresion[i]; i++) {
        char x = expresion[i];
        if (isalpha(x)) {
            printf("%c", x);
            continue;
        }
        if (x == '(') {
            push(&stack_ope, x);
            continue;
        }
        if (x == ')') {
            do {
                evaluate(&stack_ope);
            } while (peek(&stack_ope) != '(');
            pop(&stack_ope); // Sacar el abre parentesis del stack.
            continue;
        }
        //  Evaluar el stack mientras el operador actual sea de menor o igual
        //  prioridad que el operador al tope del stack.
        int prev_priority = priority(peek(&stack_ope));
        while (prev_priority != -1 && prev_priority >= priority(x)) {
            evaluate(&stack_ope);
            prev_priority = priority(peek(&stack_ope));
        }
        push(&stack_ope, x);
    }
    //  Se termino la expresión, evaluar lo que aun esta en el stack.
    while (stack_ope.ptr) {
        evaluate(&stack_ope);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Comprobación**

```
int main() {
    evaluar_expresion("a+b");
    evaluar_expresion("a+b*c");
    evaluar_expresion("(a+b)*c");
    evaluar_expresion("a+b*c+d");
    evaluar_expresion("(a+b)*(c+d)");
    evaluar_expresion("(a+b)/c+d");
    evaluar_expresion("(a+b)/(c+d)");
    evaluar_expresion("x^(a+b)+(c-d)");
}
```

produce:

```
Evaluar a+b = ab+
Evaluar a+b*c = abc*+
Evaluar (a+b)*c = ab+c*
Evaluar a*(b+c) = abc+*
Evaluar a+b*c+d = abc*+d+
Evaluar a+b*(c+d) = abcd+*+
Evaluar (a+b)*(c+d) = ab+cd+*
Evaluar (a+b)/c+d = ab+c/d+
Evaluar (a+b)/(c+d) = ab+cd+/
Evaluar x^a = xa^
Evaluar x^(a+b)+(c-d) = xab+^cd-+
```